# Error in installing PostGIS extension through PostgreSQL 11

Tags: postgresql, postgis-2.4

I am getting following issues while installing PostGIS extension.

[image]

Comment: Please remember to include the error message in the body of the question as text. This makes it legible on all devices and permits free-text search.

Comment: Hi Mustak - I can't tell if you've been to the PostGis website and downloaded the installer or zip files that postgres needs to use for this. Assuming you have done that, my next guess would be perhaps a version mismatch?  If you grab the zip file, they have a readme embedded that instructs you on what postgis elements go where in your postgres installation, which might be a way to get more information about what's gone wrong.

Comment: Hi Atcrank, actually I did what you are saying. same thing I did on another computer but working fine. It is showing issue in my system