# Enable PostGIS extensions Windows local (non-admin) with Anaconda PostgreSQL

Tags: postgis, windows, anaconda

My organisation restricts admin privs on our machines, which means that installing OSGeo4Win would require a tech to come out (and as they're stretched pretty thin and I'm likely to need regular updates at least (but very likely several goes round as I mess this up) I'd love to find a solution that avoids them).

So I was interested to see that Anaconda bundles PostgreSQL (currently 11.2) as well as GDAL, PROJ4, GEOS etc. I can download the zipped PostGIS extensions, but am not sure where they ought to go.

Anaconda has put PostgreSQL executables (initdb, psql etc) in: C:\Users...\envs\geodjango\Library\bin\, along with a host of other binaries (many dlls.) that are not PostgreSQL.

The PostGIS zip says to drop the directory structure it contains into 'the postgres folder' & 'structure should mirror what you have.' So I copied and pasted the files and folders into "Library".  I am getting this error -

```
2019-08-16 14:14:39.495 AEST [10920] ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Users/...envs/geodjango/Library/lib/rtpostgis-2.5.dll": The specified module could not be found.

2019-08-16 14:14:39.495 AEST [10920] STATEMENT:  CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not load library "C:/Users/.../envs/geodjango/Library/lib/rtpostgis-2.5.dll": The specified module could not be found.
```

but the file is there:
c:...envs\geodjango\Library\lib>dir rt*

Directory of C:\Users...\envs\geodjango\Library\lib

15/08/2019  02:18 PM           740,864 rtpostgis-2.5.dll
               1 File(s)        740,864 bytes
               0 Dir(s)  164,782,927,872 bytes free

This is exactly the same file that was "missing" for this person:
[Error in installing PostGIS extension through PostgreSQL 11](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/332130/error-in-installing-postgis-extension-through-postgresql-11)